# Card layouts and graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I define a layout of cards to be the placement of each card arbitrarily in three dimensions, observed from a particular angle. Cards cannot be bent, folded, cut or mutilated in any way.

Every layout can be represented by a graph. Each card is a node in this graph. A directed edge from one card ($u$) to another ($v$) exists if the card $u$ obscures $v$ (dependant on the orientation of the observer).

Can any simple directed graph (with no induced $2$-cycle)  be represented by a card layout? What about the converse?

NOTE: It is possible to represent a cyclic graph with cards:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you can't have both edges $u\to v$ and $v\to u$ using planar convex cards.

Comment: @Rahul Does the adjective 'simple' not imply no multiple edges?

Comment: Not according to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleDirectedGraph.html) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). $u\to v$ and $v\to u$ are two different edges, not multiple copies of the same edge.

Comment: @Rahul Is "simple directed graph with no induced $2$-cycle" better?

Comment: I don't have a proof, but I think the answer will be "yes" and "yes". Note that this becomes impractical in the real world when you have large numbers of edges incident upon a single node.

Comment: If $u \to v$, must the card representing $u$ *directly* cover the card representing $v$?  Or can there be cards in the way?

Comment: @BrianTung There can be cards in the way. For example, the graph for a stack of three cards ($p$, $q$ and $r$) would be $\{(p, q), (p, r), (q, r) \}$.

Comment: @Newb If it must be practical (in the sense of the layout being sufficiently flat) then I don't think you can have more than 6 cards (with standard size cards) covering another card without having unwanted overlaps.

Comment: @Newb Actually I have managed to get 7 and then 8 cards to work. Now I am not sure about whether I can get 9 to fit. I thought this was a simple problem! Also, If I take away the 'practical' restriction then there is still a limitation on the maximum degree of a node that depends on the thickness of the cards. It seems as though there are an infinite number of optimal packing problems contained within this question.

Comment: @Scorpion_God I don't think there's an infinite number of packing problems contained within your question, but there's at least one.